# check condition if match any of the following

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check a condition using the logical or operator and seems like I am doing that wrong. It works of course if it is just 1, but when I add other values it seems to be incorrect as in below. How do I make this work to check if it's more than one. Does something go in quotes instead?

```js
if (data.Items.find((item) => item.OrgUnit?.Id === (parseInt(match))).Role.Id === 110 || 120 || 130 || 140) {
  alert = "test"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more background as to what *exactly* you're trying to accomplish here? It's usually not the case that you'd have to have two comparisons `===` in the same expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare against multiple values like that. You could use `Array#includes` instead.

```
if([110 , 120 , 130 ,140].includes(data.Items.find((item) => item.OrgUnit?.Id === (parseInt(match))).Role.Id)){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the left side of the equation needs to be repeated for every instance of `||`

```
let roleId = data.Items.find((item) => item.OrgUnit?.Id === (parseInt(match))).Role.Id
if(roleId === 110 || roleId === 120 || roleId === 130 || roleId === 140){
  alert="test"
}
```

This could also be written like this:

```
let roleId = data.Items.find((item) => item.OrgUnit?.Id === (parseInt(match))).Role.Id
if([110,120,130,140].includes(roleId)){
  alert="test"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to iota's answer , the following part of the code could fail

```
data.Items.find((item) => item.OrgUnit?.Id === (parseInt(match))).Role.Id
```

because `find` could return undefined ,  so you need to add `?` to the result of find method

```
const values = [110,120,130,140];
const roleId = data.Items.find((item) => item.OrgUnit?.Id === (parseInt(match)))?.Role.Id
if (values.includes(roleId)) {
  alert = "test"
}
```